# cache.get('key') returns None in Django using Memcached

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am trying to use Memcache in my Django app, but it seems that something in my configuration is missing.
Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)
>>> print cache.get('my_key')
None
>>>
```

## Settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 
    }
}
```

## APIs installed:

```
$ pypm install python-memcached
$ brew install memcached
$ brew install libmemcached
```

Comment: Did you start *memcached*?

Comment: How do I do that?, I thought I just had to add it on the Django's settings

Comment: `'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:8000' ` this is supposed to be location of memcached, not Django

Comment: @vartec I already try it with 11211, without any clue'

Comment: `telnet localhost 11211` if you get `Connection refused` your memcached is not running. If you get telnet prompt, type `stats`. You should get bunch of memcached's stats, if you don't your memcache isn't configured properly

Comment: This appears to relate to installation of software on OSX, thus belongs on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @vartec! I will try it, and I'll let you know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I had some issues in my configuration, so I just installed Memcache again using MacPorts

```
$ sudo port install memcached
```

and then I ran Memcache, and it works

```
$ memcached -vv
```

These instructions have been tested on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

For more information [visit this website](https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/installing-memcached-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, just want to add that it worked for me on ubuntu machine too...

to install in ubuntu :

```
$sudo apt-get install memcached
```