# Django login 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: django

Having an issue with Django Allauth. When I log out of one user, and log back in with another, I get this issue, both locally and in production.

I'm using the latest version of Allauth, Django 3.0.5, and Python 3.7.4.

It seems like this is an Allauth issue, but I haven't seen it reported online anywhere else. So just wondering what I can do next to troubleshoot. Login works fine, less I just logged out of another user.

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
Exception Location: /Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py in authentication_failed, line 507
Python Executable:  /Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf']
Server time:    Thu, 16 Apr 2020 17:53:52 -0700

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.postgres',
 'common',
 'bootstrap4',
 's3direct',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
 'import_export',
 'tinymce',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'dashboard',
 'marketing']
Installed Middleware:
('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 138, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 81, in dispatch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 103, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 179, in clean
    **credentials)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 497, in authenticate
    self.authentication_failed(request, **credentials)
  File "/Users/[USERDIR]/Sites/frontline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 507, in authentication_failed
    data.append(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/login/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Looking at the code it seems that the failed login attempts cache is returning `None`: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py#L505-L513 - setting `ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT` to `0` should fix it but only if you don't want that feature.

Comment: How are you handling your cache? It seems to be an issue with that

Comment: Thank you @Ashley! This fixed it.

Comment: The problem with keeping this enabled in a production environment is that it will allow attackers unlimited attempts when brute forcing password guesses against your application. You probably want a better long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `allauth` packages to the top of installed apps and try again.
It can be a problem of conflicts since the default `django.contrib.auth` package is on the top of hierarchy and when django looks through the installed apps, it stops on the first one that matches it's criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`allauth` code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/b52a61b4d5c74c586f032c761cd0f902df20fd4b/allauth/account/adapter.py#L505),

```py
def authentication_failed(self, request, **credentials):
  if app_settings.LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT:
    cache_key = self._get_login_attempts_cache_key(
      request, **credentials
    )
    data = cache.get(cache_key, [])
    dt = timezone.now()
    data.append(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
    cache.set(cache_key, data, app_settings.LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT)
```

it seems that for some reason the cache is storing a `None` value for the login attempts key (note that it's ignoring the default value, `[]`). Is the `CACHE` settings variable [set-up correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/)?

Looking around, there seems to be [some issues with memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384197/cache-getkey-returns-none-in-django-using-memcached), if that's what you're using (*Edit: I now think that isn't possible since the Django code just [sets the value to the default](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py#L163) if the result is `None`, no matter if it's actually that or the key is not present, due to [`python-memcached` limitations](https://github.com/linsomniac/python-memcached/issues/159)*). This is very strange behavior, you could just deactivate this feature as suggested in the comments, but it seems to be an underlying issue waiting to bite.